# Jquery .data returns "undefined

Tags: jquery, html, undefined

I've looked at the other posts and their solutions don't help.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 3">3</button>
</div>

<div class="grid-item grid-item-double-height item-1" data-button-type="interior">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/lazyload-ph.png" data-src="img/slurp-004.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I've tried the following jquery:

```
$(".btn-group").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var push = $(this).data("button-type");
  alert(push);
});
```

and

```
$(".btn-group").on('click', function(e) {
var push = $(this).data("button-type");
alert(push);
});
```

and

```
$(".btn-group").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var push = $(this).attr("data-button-type");
  alert(push);
});
```

and I tried this last one because I read that using "this" referred to the outer most element

```
$("buttn").on('click', function(e) {
  var push = $(this).data("button-type");
  alert(push);
});
```

and

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
  var push = $(this).data("button-type");
  alert(push);
});
```

I also tried it without the "e" as in :

```
function(e) {
```

became

```
function() {
```

In each case I get "undefined". From all my research I can't figure out what the problem is.

Thank you,
Richard Belotte

Comment: What is your expectation in the `push` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close.

While using `.data()` in jQuery it is treated a bit differently.

When you use :

`$(.someClass).data('myAttribute')`

it is handled by jQuery as:

```
<div class='.someClass' data-my-attribute></div>
```

---

So for your case: you would use it like the following code:

```js
$(".btn-group").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  //this points to the button clicked. So either you use the below code
  //or you should directly select the grid item.
  //This works too
  //var push = $('.grid-item').data("buttonType");
  var push = $(this).parent().siblings('.grid-item').data("buttonType");
  alert(push);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 3">3</button>
</div>

<div class="grid-item grid-item-double-height item-1" data-button-type="interior">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/lazyload-ph.png" data-src="img/slurp-004.jpg" class="img-responsive lazyload"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use a comment to say thank you... but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
  $(".grid-item").on('click', 'button', function(e) {
      var push = $(this).data("button-type");
      alert(push);
  })
```

The class name which is is attached to the event listener is wrong, there is no data-button-type attribute in btn-group classed used.